# Laravel spark for existing projects?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I see Laravel Spark has been released! Great news.

Now, in the [docs](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation),

it says that you need to install it on a fresh laravel.

> spark new project-name

If you do install it manually, you just have to download spark folder unpack in your project.

https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation#manual-download

In the other hand, I have a line about [update process](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation#updating-spark):

So I'm a little confused, as I can't try the product before buying it.

Is it posible to use spark with my existing project?

What should happen when I already developped Login, Register, Invite system for instance...

Should I use Spark Login or Invite system instead of mine? If I do so, I should get a better integration with Spark?

Well that's a lot of questions for a single question, but I feel kind of blind just seeing product through Laracasts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got my Answers in [FAQ](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/faq#existing):

> Can Spark be integrated into an existing application?
>
> Spark is not designed to be integrated into existing applications. Spark is designed for new applications.